# how to update Navigation entity with Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client.Dynamics

Tags: dynamics-crm-online, dataverse

I am using Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client.Dynamics package to update CRM entity.

to update a normal field,

```
entity.Attributes["ecg_proposal_url"] = sendURL ;
await client.UpdateAsync(entity);
```

works fine. but when I try the same with a navigation field (pointing to user) , I get error:

"CRM do not support direct update of Entity Reference properties, Use Navigation properties instead"
The search did not show any example. Also the DOCs are very slim.
How do I update it with field name "_ecg_proposal_written_by_value" ?
Thank you.
The code that causes the error is:

```
entity.Attributes["_ecg_proposal_written_by_value"] = writtenByID;
```

Or

```
entity.Attributes["ecg_proposal_written_by"] = writtenByID;
```

it should have a user ID

Comment: are you using the C# SDK (as your example) or the OData endpoint (the field name _ecg_proposal_written_by_value)?

Comment: Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client.Dynamics is the new C# SDK

Comment: so can you post the code that generated the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a lookup field needs to specify the table associated with it.
With the C# SDK you need to assign a `EntityReference` object.

Something like:

```
entity["ecg_proposal_written_by"] = new EntityReference("systemuser", writtenByID);
```

assuming the lookup points to the systemuser (User) table.

Note that with the C# SDK you need to use the logical name of the field (`ecg_proposal_written_by`) and not the name used with Web API / OData 4.0 syntax (in your case `_ecg_proposal_written_by_value`)